# What is returned from std::vector::data() when the vector is empty?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

Given this example:

```
// "C" function prototype:
void foo(const int*);

// code:
std::vector<int> v;
foo(v.data());
```

Is it guaranteed by the standard that `v.data()` on an empty vector will produce a null pointer?  I don't understand this wording:

```
"The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a
valid range, even if the container is empty (data() is not
dereferenceable in that case)."
```

I see that on VS2015 it does indeed produce a null pointer, but I was worried some implementations might return a pointer to some internal scratch buffer within vector.

Comment: It looks legal to return a non-null, non-dereferenceable pointer. However, if the only guarantee is that you can access the half-open range `[data(), data()+size())`, and that range is empty ... than any code that _tries_ to dereference it is already incorrect.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pass an `int*` pointer to `foo()` without also passing the number of `int`s being pointed to, unless `foo()` has a requirement that the pointer must point to a specific number of `int`s that the caller must pre-allocate.

Comment: I think the "valid range" phrase stems from not being allowed to point to arbitrary memory with arbitrarily typed pointers. I think the standard is just trying to say that an implementation may not return a pointer that produces a trap upon being formed, so you may pass that pointer around legally (but not necessarily dereference it).

Comment: Looks like it may return `nullptr` but there is no quarantees. It could be similar to `new T[0]`

Comment: @Slava Not that it can come from that, unless the implementation caches it for all instances to use, as the default-ctor must be noexcept...

Comment: You can *call* `.data` on an empty container and you can pass around the result. You just can't dereference it; and ensuring you don't do so is *your responsibility*. At least, that's how *I* read it.

Comment: @Deduplicator No, it could.  `std` library is part of the compiler implementation, and if knows that `::new T[0]` cannot throw (even if it isn't noexcept) it would be permitted to use it.  (I'm ignoring the possibility of array new being overloaded on a `T`)

Comment: "I see that on VS2015 it does indeed produce a null pointer" - what happens on any specific implementation/compiler/version is *no guarantee* that the same will happen elsewhere. Only if you follow the letter of the law (the C++ standard) are you guaranteed behaviour across platforms and compilers.

Comment: @Useless The problem comes when std::vector is used as a replacement for C-style arrays.  I was hoping that data() would be guaranteed to degrade to a nullptr when the vector is empty, but was worried that the documentation doesn't explicitly state this.  Looks like I was right to worry about it.